# Internet Explorer - save id/pass with pages which don't allow to save

Tags: internet-explorer, passwords

I'm working with some web apps that don't implement "save password" feature, therefore, I'm forced to type id/password many many times :(.
So I post this question to ask how can I save password in my web browser so I will automatically fill id & password for me so I just have to click on "Login" button.
Thanks

---

Some try with KeePass & I meet it's bug in auto-paste id/pass with IE9, but for Firefox, it works well.

---

Still searching...

Answer (score 3):

Use something like [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) or [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/), both of which have auto-type functionality. (KeePass isn't even limited to web sites.)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't indicated that the solution **must** entail Internet Explorer, so here is another option :)

Firefox + Greasemonkey extension + the Auto-Complete override script will allow all form fields to be saved (including those set to autocomplete=no) and all passwords via the password manager.

Answer (score 0):

follow these links to clarify your issues.. may be you will get what's going on your machine..

http://www.watchingthenet.com/how-to-force-internet-explorer-7-to-save-web-site-password-after-answering-no.html

http://www.mediacollege.com/microsoft/internet-explorer/autocomplete.html

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2004/07/15/Internet-Explorer-on-Windows-XP-doesn_2700_t-save-password.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306895

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party. Nevertheless, you can try [Allow Password Save](http://www.howtogeek.com/62980/how-to-force-your-browser-to-remember-passwords/) hack by How-To Geek. This works in IE 11 and Firefox 25.